# AD FS response has Issuer HTTP when we expect HTTPS

Tags: xml, https, adfs

Our app sends a SamlRequest to our AD FS.

In the response XML the Issuer is "http://[server_name]/adfs/services/trust".

What do I need to do, on the AD FS configuration, to make the Issuer in the response become HTTPS instead of HTTP?

EDIT

When I was testing it inside our company, the AD FS was returning HTTPS, so this is what I coded for. It has gone to the customer and their AD FS is returning HTTP.

If we look at our AD FS Federation XML, it shows the EntityId = "https://[server_name]/adfs/services/trust".

As I understand it, the default EntityId = "http://[server_name]/adfs/services/trust"

We are not sure how our EntityId has become HTTPS.

Comment: The request/response is the same connection which is encrypted.  So https isn't really needed for the data inside an encrypted response.  So why do you expect https?

Comment: @jdweng When I was testing it inside our company, the AD FS was returning HTTPS, so this is what 
I coded for.  It has gone to the customer and their AD FS is returning HTTP.

Comment: HTTPS uses TLS for encryption so you need to enable TLS.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2-server?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng do you mean on the AD FS machine?

Comment: Yes.  The windows Server.

Comment: @jdweng they already have TLS enabled.  Any other ideas why their ADFS is sending Issuer as HTTP?

Comment: Than if you send HTTPS you  should get back HTTPS.  IF not than you are going through a Proxy Server and need to turn proxy off.  Maybe this will help : https://github.com/department-of-veterans-affairs/lighthouse-saml-proxy/blob/master/README.md?force_isolation=true#using-logingov-with-local-saml-proxy

Comment: Are you going from a windows network to a linux network? You are then going through a bridge.  The bridge is behind a firewall and may just have HTTPS disabled.  If there is a proxy the proxy may have an error so best is just to bypass.

Comment: @jdweng it is only the Issuer in the response XML that is HTTP.  From what I have read recently this is normal.  Issuer is set according to the EntityId and the default EntityId is usually HTTP.  It seems we have done something to our ADFS which has changed the EntityId from the default HTTP to HTTPS.  If we knew what, the customer could do the same.

Comment: There is a web.xml file and schema that I think need fixing.  See : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/web_xml.htm?force_isolation=true#WBAPP503

Answer (score 0):

You can change the EntityId/Issuer of your AD FS like this:

[image]

[image]

Ours was set to HTTPS.